# PHPMailerAutoload success message,but not sending any emails

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send an email using the gmail smtp server as a relay in php. I am programming in webmatrix server and I use PHPMailerAutoload library to send the emails.My operating system is windows 7 64 bit.I already have configured php.ini to use gmail smtp server.When running the code i get the success message but no emails is sent.Could anyone please help me find the problem,thanks.Here is part of my code:

```
     $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

           //Send mail using gmail
           if($send_using_gmail){
           $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // sets the prefix to the servier
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
    $mail->Port = 465; // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username = "example"; // GMAIL username
    $mail->Password = "password"; // GMAIL password
}

//Typical mail data
$mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
$mail->SetFrom("example@gmail.com", "name");
$mail->Subject = "My Subject";
$mail->Body = "Mail contents";
$mail->SMTPDebug = true;

try{
    $mail->Send();
    echo "Success!";

} catch(Exception $e){
    //Something went bad
    echo "Fail - " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: what kind of error do you get?

Comment: I get no errors but the email is not sent.

Comment: did you import the phpmail wrapper file?

Comment: No,how can i install it on windows?

Answer (score 0):

Download the wrapper file 
[PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), import the file as shown below.

```
 require '../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

       //Send mail using gmail
     if($send_using_gmail){
       $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
       $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
       $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // sets the prefix to the servier
       $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
       $mail->Port = 465; // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
       $mail->Username = "example"; // GMAIL username
      $mail->Password = "password"; // GMAIL password
    }

 //Typical mail data
    $mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
    $mail->SetFrom("example@gmail.com", "name");
    $mail->Subject = "My Subject";
    $mail->Body = "Mail contents";
    $mail->SMTPDebug = true;

    try{
       $mail->Send();
       echo "Success!";

     } catch(Exception $e){
    //Something went bad
        echo "Fail - " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
     }
```

Comment: I have already imported this file but it is not working,As I said it does not show any error messages but the mail is not sent.

Comment: use tls instead of ssl and use port 587